# Spring @EnableAsync breaks bean initialization order?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway, spring-async

I wanted to introduce `@Async` methods (for sending mails in parallel) in my SpringBoot application.
But when I put the `@EnableAsync` annotation on our application's main `@Configuration` class (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`), the Flyway DB migrations are executed before the `DataSourceInitializer` (which runs schema.sql and data.sql for my tests) executed.

The first operation involving a 'should-be-migrated' database table fails.

Removing the `@EnableAsync` puts everything back to normal. Why does this happen and how could I fix this (or work around the issue)?

**Update** Some more findings: `@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)` keeps the original order of DB setup, but the `@Async` method runs on the same thread as caller thread then. I also saw that the Bean 'objectPostProcessor' is created early (3rd bean) when `@EnableAsync` is not present, or `@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)` is used. When only `@EnableAsync` is used, this bean is created much later.

**Update 2** While I wasn't able to create a minimal project which reproduces the problem yet, I found out that the proper DB setup order is restored in my affected application when I comment out the `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` in the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{ 
  ...
}
```

Bean 'webSocketConfig' is the first bean created (as per INFO-level console output) if `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` is present.

Comment: Do you get any errors from Flyway? How do you make sure that the async stuff still only runs after the migration has completed?

Comment: Please check my update on the question. Actually, migration seems to work fine, the entire DB is recreated later on.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You need to run the migration code before you try to use the database. Why do you want to run it "asynchronously"?

Comment: No, I don't want to run any of the database stuff asynchronously. The async stuff I want to do is about sending emails. But when I introduce `@EnableAsync` on my main configuration, the migration is attempted before the database was set up. Let me know which part of the question was confusing, I'll try to correct that.

Comment: The symptom isn't the same, but I wonder if it's caused by https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14030

Comment: @AndyWilkinson The explanation of the linked spring issue is a bit too much under the hood for me, but I added more of the findings I made. Maybe this helps you correlate.

Comment: @sorrymissjackson It helps a bit but not enough to pinpoint the problem. Could you share a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hm, I'll see what I can do. Minimal won't be small I guess.

Comment: Doh! Removing basically everything from the app's behavior and special configuration restores proper application startup: first the database is created and then the migration takes place. And: `@Async` method is indeed executed async. Now it's getting really difficult.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I found the cause for my problem, please check my answer. I think that it is somewhat related to the issue you referenced.

Comment: @sorrymissjackson Glad to hear you got to the bottom of it. Thanks for writing it up in such detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that having both `@EnableAsync` and `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` present in my application caused the described effect.

Removing one of it, restored the expected behavior, in which case the `DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor` created the `DataSourceInitializer` which triggered execution of schema.sql and data.sql, before flyway migrations took place.

When both annotations were present, the registration of the `BeanPostProcessor` named `internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor` happened before the `DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor` was registered.

The cause of the problem was that the registration of `internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor` caused the creation of the `dataSource` bean as a side effect. This side effect was caused by spring looking for a `TaskExecutor` bean to use, for the `@Async` method execution. spring unexpectedly picked up the  `clientInboundChannelExecutor` bean which was present because of the `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`. Using this bean caused the instantiation of `WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration` which created the `objectMapper` bean (for json-serialization) which uses services that use DAO-repositories which depend on `dataSource`. So all those beans got created.

Because `DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor` wasn't even registered at that time, `DataSourceInitializer` was created much later, after the flyway migration took place.

The javadoc for `@EnableAsync` says the following:

> By default, a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor will be used to process async method invocations. Besides, annotated methods having a void return type cannot transmit any exception back to the caller. By default, such uncaught exceptions are only logged.

I assumed, that a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` will be created to run the `@Async` methods, but instead spring picked up an existing bean with a matching type.

So the **solution** for this issue **was to implement** `AsyncConfigurer`, and provide my own `Executor`. This is also suggested in the javadoc of `@EnableAsync`:

> To customize all this, implement AsyncConfigurer and provide:
>   * your own Executor through the getAsyncExecutor() method, and
>   * your own AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler through the getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() method.

With this tweak the DB setup is again executed as expected.